# validate html, problem in my doctype and use of lan(g)

Tags: html, validation, doctype, w3c-validation

I can't get my website validated; it jumps an error on my doctype which is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//ES" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

(under Spanish)

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

(under English)...

**The html tag:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="EN" lan="en">
```

THE ERROR

```
Error: unrecognized DOCTYPE; unable to check document
```

any idea why?

Comment: That doctype looks correct to me, and it validates correctly when I try it, too. What validator are you using?

Comment: the w3c and http://htmlhelp.com/cgi-bin/validate.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Ffuncook.com%2F&warnings=yes

Comment: - Apparently, putting the language code at the end of DOCTYPE public part is quite a common authoring mistake. I'm curious, where did you get the idea that on a Spanish page it should end "//ES"?

Comment: i got that in tutorials. especially this one: http://keepyourlinks.com/browser.php?id=68024 . do you think is not correct? i'm not sure if i understood the first part of your comment... :S

Answer (score 5):

do not specify the language in the `doctype` but always use:

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" .......
```

Set the language in the `<html>` tag: `<html lang="es">`

- http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html#DTD
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/

Comment: i'm getting indexed already. you think it's a good idea to do so?

Comment: updating post with my <html> tag :)

Comment: still the //ES in your doctype must be //EN

Answer (score 3):

I use this one, which is the same, except for the `html` in lowercase. I'm not sure if that would matter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Dit you check if there's any whitespace before the doctype?

Comment: Could be, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Could you post some code to explain?

Answer (score 2):

The upper/lower case issue of "html" is described here: [Recommended Doctype Declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)